# Ansible pattern : members of group A and group B + members of group C

Tags: ansible, limit

Given he following inventory :

```
[GroupA]
host1
host2
host3

[GroupB]
host1
host4
host5

[GroupC]
host2

[GroupD]
host3
```

How can I write the limit pattern to run on members of (GroupA and GroupB), plus members of group C ?
With the given example I should run on host1 and host2.

I tried things like :

```
GroupA:&GroupB,GroupC

GroupA:&GroupB:&GroupC

GroupC:GroupA:&GroupB
```

with no success.

What is the good syntax for this please ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: To my surprise, this is not possible only with patterns. A workarround in this case is playing both with patterns and a limit, e.g. `ansible -i yourinventory.ini GroupA:GroupC -l GroupB:GroupC -m debug -a var=inventory_hostname`

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be expressed with a normal host pattern. The processing of operations like `&` in patterns is done in a [specific order](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/dfda04894f25a9f491b5bde7ae051da01d12d654/lib/ansible/inventory/manager.py#L66-L91) that is intended to produce consistent behaviour.

It is possible through templating, where the order of operations is under your control.

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ groups.GroupA | intersect(groups.GroupB) | union(groups.GroupC) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
```

Result:

```
PLAY [['host1', 'host2']] ******************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but since the limit has to come from AWX I don't see how to pass this...